# Java Regular Expression to match only method name in signature

Tags: java, regex, text-processing

I have a list of strings that represents method signatures. For example:

```
public String someMethod(String parameter)

public static void someAnotherMethod(double doubleParam, List<String> stringList)
```

By using the following regular expression (link https://regex101.com/r/TwRRbp/1), I can get the method name and arguments:

```
\w+\(.*\)
```

Finally, I get the following:

```
someMethod(String parameter)

someAnotherMethod(double doubleParam, List<String> stringList)
```

But I only need the method name. I guess that I need to focus on the opening parenthesis.

Comment: Sure, you need `\w+(?=\()`, see https://regex101.com/r/TwRRbp/1

Comment: Wow that's cool. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty much correct. Using positive Lookahead you can match any word character that's followed by an opening parenthesis. If you want to be really sure, you can search for words, followed by parenthesis and a curly bracket:

```
(\w+)(?=\(.*\)\s*\{)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?=\()
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Dp91Xc/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z0-9_]+            any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
                           '0' to '9', '_' (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```